# equally-likely discrete probability models

Tags: self-study

[image]

I am not really sure about the answer of question b. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Think about using the compliment rule, i.e., $$P(A)=1-P(A^c)$$ then you don't have to calculate an infinite series. This is of course just a hint, but if you need more please do say so.

Comment: Is the answer 1-3/n ?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info. Please add your own thoughts about the problem.

Comment: That is not the answer.

Comment: Is it linked to question (a) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be the value of the outcome of the experiment, then

\begin{align}
P(k>3)&=1-P(k\leq3)\\
&=1-[P(k=1)+P(k=2)+P(k=3)]\\
&=1-\left[\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4^2}+\frac{3}{4^3}\right]\\
&=0.015625
\end{align}

=====================================================================

If you didn't use the complement rule, then the answer would be 
$$P(k>3)=\sum_{i=4}^\infty\frac{3}{4^k}=0.015625$$ which is indeed an infinite sum.

Comment: I was first thinking that both questions are not interrelated . By the way , thanks for helping .